# How to handle items data binding with vaadin grid when using dataProvider

Tags: javascript, vaadin-grid, polymer-3.x

I am using the following example from vaadin docs with polymer3

```
<vaadin-grid id="grid" aria-label="Remote Data Example">
  <vaadin-grid-column path="firstName"></vaadin-grid-column>
  <vaadin-grid-column path="lastName"></vaadin-grid-column>
  <vaadin-grid-column path="email"></vaadin-grid-column>
</vaadin-grid>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    const grid = document.querySelector('vaadin-grid');

    grid.size = 200;
    grid.dataProvider = function(params, callback) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).result);
      };
      var index = params.page * params.pageSize;
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://demo.vaadin.com/demo-data/1.0/people?index=' + index + '&count=' + params.pageSize, true);
      xhr.send();
    };
  });
</script>
```

I could not figure out how to update a row from the loaded items using polymer data binding

I have tried to access the `items` property in the grid using `this.$.grid.items` but this always returns the number of items

I want to be able to do something like 
`this.$.grid.items[0].firstName = 'changed'` and refelct the change into the grid

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, there's no API for updating a single item when `dataProvider` is used. One option is to use `grid.clearCache()` that makes grid request data for the visible rows again. Of course, storing the items in an additional cache would be useful in this case to avoid unnecessary server requests. If you use `path` or `renderer`, you can also invoke `grid.render()` after changing an item sub-property.

see [vaadin/vaadin-grid#1526](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/1526) and the related forum thread

Comment: I wonder., is there any method to only call updated rows on making a API call to pass updated data to backend API service?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'grid.clearCache()' in vaadin 14, where can I find it?